# How should I prepare for Mutant Bash TV?

Tags: rage

To get my sponsorship for an upgraded car in Rage, I had to do Mutant Bash TV and luckily was pretty well supplied with shotgun ammo. **But what would be the ideal way to prepare for farming Mutant Bash TV?**

[image]

Should I simply stockpile on shotgun ammo, given how powerful it is? Or would one of the automatic riffles be more effective in close quarters? Or would any of the drones, like the turret be of use as well?

I'm planning on doing it a couple of times, because shooting mutants is fun and the pay is very good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone through multiple times just using the shotgun, wing sticks, and sniper rifle.  If mutants get close to you the shotgun is a one shot kill.  Wing sticks are great just to cut their heads off.  I use the melee (with the gun butt, not fists) a lot too.  Head shots using melee are pretty easily done.

I pull out the sniper rifle only for the slots wheels.

However, if you want to have some fun with it use a rocket launcher and watch blood fly.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible approach

Comment: Yeah, it has worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

The best way possible is by getting advanced wingsticks. (For those who haven't got this far, it isn't much of a spoiler) Once you put in disc two, follow the mission line until you have acsess to walk around and not be interrupted by people. Go upstairs and across the way of Mayor Redstones office there is a store owned by a lady called Jani. Look through her items until you find the 'Advanced Wingsticks'. Buy this plan and create some wingsticks. (Current windsticks will automatically become advanced) They are created the same as normal ones. (Buy the parts, trust me) Buying the parts will save you $24 dollars everytime you make some. Once you have enough, go back to Wellspring by taking the safe passage and and changing discs when prompt.

Now, for the cash making. Head to Mutant Bash and start your Re-Run. The entire time you are playing, use only your wingsticks. You will need at least 40 everytime you enter. Advanced lets you hit up to 3 enemies at a time and has a better chance of it surviving a bounce off walls and the ground. Once you repeat this enough you'll start getting 100% Accuracy which means more cash for you. You're looking at spending $102 on wingsticks each run. But also making at least $750 profit in the end, even if you make the 'Mutant Jackpot' in the bonus round. The best part? You'll in average do a run in 2:30:00 almost everytime. Do this as many times as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Pop Rockets. This shotgun ammo should kill any common mutant in 1 (near) hit. Keep in mind that you can play *Mutant Bash TV* as many times as you want. Sentry turrets will get quickly overrun, so sentry bots do last longer thanks to their mêlée attacks. Also, lots of wingsticks as well. If the mutant is at a good distance from you, you should get the wingstick back.